# How should I find inner corners in this kind of chessboard(paterrn size is(2,2))

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Nowadays I get such kind of chessboard for fisheye calibration.[chessboard_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJw1n.png) But findChessboardCorners() can only works both pattern size's width and height is bigger than 2.Here is my questions:

1. How can I detect this chessboard and find inner corners by changing CV source code(I don't care the order of output)
2. It would be great if someone can tell me why pattern size needed to be bigger than 2

I have tried goodFeaturesToTrack(),but it doesn't work well [goodFeaturesToTrack_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwnTc.png)

Thanks in advence!

Comment: why the size minimum? probably a sanity check. -- browse the source or read up on the theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard_detection

Comment: second question answer is simpley: because it was designed in that way